# Why is total time taken by Google Dataflow more than sum of times taken by individual steps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

[image: A simple dataflow job]

I am really unable to understand why is the total elapsed time for a dataflow job so much higher than time taken by individual steps.

For example, total elapsed time for the dataflow in picture is 2 min 39 sec. While time spent in individual steps is just 10 sec. Even if we consider the time spent in setup and destroy phases, there is a difference of 149 secs, which is too much.

Is there some other way of reading the individual stage timing or I am missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: When you run a job, Dataflow spends a few minutes (2-5) allocating worker machines, and setting them up to run your job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me 2 min 39 sec time is fine. You are doing this operation reading file and then pardo and then writting it to bigquery.

There are lot of factor involved in this time calculation.

1. How much data you need to process. i.e - in your case I don't think you are processing much data.
2. What computation you are doing. i.e your pardo step is only 3 sec so apart from small amount of data pardo do not have much computation as well.
3. Writing it to bigquery - i.e in your case it is taking only 5 sec.

So creation and destroy phases of the dataflow remains constant. In your case it is 149 sec. Your job is taking only 10 sec that is dependent on all three factor I explained above.

Now let assume that you have to process 2 million record And each record transform take 10 sec. In this case the time will be much higher i.e 10 sec * 2 million records for single node dataflow load job.

So in this case 149 sec didn't stands in-front of whole job completion time as 149 sec is considered for all record process 0 sec * 2 million records.

Hope these information help you to understand the timing.

Comment: You know what when you put these 149 secs in the perspective of 2 million records, it does put things clearly :)